# Stuck trying to align things HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

So I keep trying to align images and text to the center and they keep appearing on the left side of the screen can someone help.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="borderexample3">
        <font color="white" class=>&nbsp;Recent News</font>
      </p>
    </div>
    <h1><font color="white"><font face="roboto-bold,roboto,sans-serif"<h1 align="right">Keep Updated!</font></h1>
    <div style="text-align: center"><img src="assets/img/fwah.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what shows up.

http://prntscr.com/kgc5c2

I would like it where my red guidelines are on this image.

http://prntscr.com/kgc5tn

Comment: Your HTML is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing your columns using `col-sm-push-#`.

```
<div class="col-sm-push-3 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
```

Comment: tried however it wont let me line it up into the middle

Comment: Make sure your image is set as a block-level element in order to use the 'margin:auto style.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="container" align="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to add the following lines in wherever you want to make it center:

```
 style="text-align:center;"
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="borderexample3" style="text-align:center;">
        <font color="black" class="">&nbsp;Recent News</font>
      </p>
    </div>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;"><font color="black"><font face="roboto-bold,roboto,sans-serif"<h1 align="right">Keep Updated!</font></h1>
    <div style="text-align: center"><img src="assets/img/fwah.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```